# Allow network interface access and usage to root only

Tags: linux, networking

I have several unprivileged users on my system and do not want them to directly use a network interface, but use my network-bridge application instead. In my specific case it is a CAN interface on a RaspberryPi.

I have everything ready, but don't know how to restrict the network interface access. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewall (IP tables) rules should be editable by super user only. You can create a group based policy to block access to certain interface.

https://askubuntu.com/a/423105